# javascript bigmath issue

Tags: javascript, math

I have the following piece of code to calculate how far back in the future a day lies

```
    var totalPixels = this._endX - this._startX;
    var segmentPixels = this._nowX - this._startX;
    var startTime = this._nowDate.getTime() - Timeline._minToMs((segmentPixels/totalPixels*this._rangeInMinutes));
    //console.log(this._nowDate.getTime() + '\n' + Timeline._minToMs(segmentPixels/totalPixels*this._rangeInMinutes));
    this._startDate.setTime(startTime);
    console.log(this._rangeInMinutes + ', ' + this._startDate.toString());
```

Typical values are

endX: 1037

startX: 40

nowX: 134.625

rangeInMinutes ranges from 1 to the number of minutes in a year.

minToMs simply multiplies the input by 60*1000.

My output varies from my expected output by roughly a factor of ten. Am I experiencing a rounding error, or some sort of truncation in the process of converting minutes to milliseconds?

P.S.: A fiddle of what I'm trying to do is http://jsfiddle.net/NRx9m/21/

Comment: Please post typical values of nowX, endX and startX

Comment: I'd also personally suggest in addition to providing those values that you also tell us what your expected output is and your actual output. And possibly even why you expect a given output (it may be that the program is right and you are wrong for all we know).

Comment: @mplungjan: I edited the question to include typical values.

Comment: @Chris: The expected value is an integer that represents a date roughly roughly a year before now. Instead I get an integer representing a date roughly a month before now. rangeInMinutes is a number obtained by a slider with output in range (1, numberOfMinutesPerYear).

Comment: is _nowX 134625 or 134.625, e.g. is it a decimal point or a European thousand separator?

Comment: @mplungjan: the dot is a decimal point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your output is startTime and I assume that _nowDate is as I'd expect, the date now.

So `Timeline._minToMs((segmentPixels/totalPixels*this._rangeInMinutes));` should be your approximate year you are expecting to take off from now?

This figure is going to change depending on rangeInMinutes. From the figures you've given the value you are subtracting is `0.0879*_rangeInMinutes` and then converted to ms.

If you are getting a value of a month before then I'd assume that your value of rangeInMinutes is approximately 500,000.

With a given value of 500,000 it will be about 30.5 days before now that you will get out.

Could you describe the maths you use to explain why you think that your output should be a year before now (apparently with no variation in the rangeInMinutes variable).

Alternatively hearing about what your rangeInMinutes is might help too...

**Edit:**

OK. Looking at the code in the fiddle, playing around a bit and seeing what its up to I think it does what I think I'd expect...

Looking at the core bits of this as follows:

I'm assuming that startX, endX and nowX represent a pixel position on a timeline chart.

```
// number of pixels representing the range from 
var totalPixels = endX - startX; startdate to enddate
// Number of pixels representing the range from startdate to nowdate
var segmentPixels = nowX - startX;
```

The following I have rearranged slightly so I can label it more intuitively (I hope)

```
var startTime = nowTime 
    - Math.floor(
        (rangeInMilliseconds / totalPixels) //time per pixel
        * segmentPixels // pixels between now and start
        );
```

You could also work out endTime if you wanted to:

```
var endTime = nowTime 
    + Math.floor(
        (rangeInMilliseconds / totalPixels) //time per pixel
        * (endX-nowX) // pixels between now and start
        );
```

Here's a fiddle I've done - http://jsfiddle.net/MWCbW/

As you can see the startdate is december and the end date is november. The reason for not being an exact year is because your year is 48 weeks long due to the way you've worked out second in a year (or month more precisely).

So I reckon that the year difference is there. Its just that you're perhaps not following where it is exactly.... Obviously you need to use a scale of 100 to get this result since otherwise our daterange will be something less than a year.

Comment: The complete code is at http://code.google.com/p/timeline-js/source/browse/Timeline.js

However, I'll set up a fiddle with just the values in question. Thanks for looking at my problem!

Comment: Well, I can see from your fiddle that if I put in a range of 100 that you get a date that is approximately 1 month ago. This seems to match what you are trying to do. I'll edit my answer though because its long winded...

Comment: I think I got it, by using a slider-max value that is greater than maxIn, I can get to years instead of a month. In other words, the slider value for which the start date is earlier than a year from now is greater than 100. I didn't know that was possible. In the repo I linked to earlier, I have code that shows the user based on the rangeInMilliseconds whether the current selection is in minute's, hour's, day's, month's, or year's range. The output would read years, indicating that rangeInMilliseconds is greater than a year, but the date was only a month earlier. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Posting a working example for Joshua. I do not see what could be the problem other than the decimal point in nowX

```
<script>
var x = new Object();
x._minToMs=function(min){  return min*60000; }
x._endX = 1037;
x._startX = 40
x._nowX = 134625; // WITHOUT the decimal point, this gives months instead of weeks
var totalPixels = x._endX - x._startX;
segmentPixels = x._nowX - x._startX;
x._nowDate=new Date();
x._startDate=new Date();
x._rangeInMinutes = 1000;
var startTime = parseInt(x._nowDate.getTime() - x._minToMs((segmentPixels/totalPixels*x._rangeInMinutes)));
x._startDate.setTime(startTime);
alert(x._rangeInMinutes + ', ' + x._startDate.toString());

</script>
```

Comment: You have got the wrong value for nowX though... He has 124.625. I set up a fiddle with this correct value and it is not right (http://jsfiddle.net/ux6tS/) . However, this could go some way to contributing towards his problem.

Comment: I read `nowX: 134.625` and I removed the decimal. If I do not, I get a value a few hours away instead of a few months

Comment: Its all down to the scale of rangeInMinutes it seems. That range is the year he's looking for. So a value of a few hours away when your range is about 17 hours is about what I'd expect...